# Python - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable Exit Code at CodeWars - Are they the same?

Tags: python

So I'm doing a challenge from CodeWars that says:

"Given two arrays a and b write a function comp(a, b) that checks whether the two arrays have the "same" elements, with the same multiplicities. "Same" means, here, that the elements in b are the elements in a squared, regardless of the order."

My code for it is:

```
def comp(array1, array2):
    if array1==None or array2==None:
        return False
    array1 = list(array1)
    array2 = list(array2)
    array1.sort()
    array2.sort()
    z= 0
    for i in range(len(array1)):
            if array1[i]**2 == array2[i]:
                z+=1
    if z == len(array1):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Now, I know there must be much easier code for this task, but I'm still a beginner programmer.

So all the tests are passed positively.
But I keep getting an exit code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    test.assert_equals(comp(a1, a2), False)
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 10, in comp
   if array1[i]**2 == array2[i]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If I remove the first "if array1= None.... return False" statement, it gives this exit code instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    test.assert_equals(comp(a1, a2), False)
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 3, in comp
    array2 = list(array2)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

So no matter what, my code has something wrong in it, haha. Any solution to this?

Comment: think about what happens if the lists don't have the same length

Comment: according to your Traceback `a2` is `None`. `print(a2)` before line 18 in main.py. Then check how you assign `a2`.

Comment: Well, I suppose it must return False, but when I add an "if len(array1) != len(array2): return False" statement, it gives me an "if len(array1) != len(array2):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()" Exit Code :(

Comment: You need to use `is None`, not `==None`

Comment: And if you are already given two arrays, `list()`  isn't needed, and order isn't important, so not sure why you need to sort anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you can cam be dueto different lenghts of lists -you do not guard against that.

```
comp([1,2,3], [1,2])
```

You can simplify your code using `enumerate()` on one array and then look into the other one. I highly doubt your arrays need to be cast into a list - they probably already are - and even if, you could do that in one step using `sorted()`:

```
def comp(array1, array2):
    if array1 is None or array2 is None: # compare to None with is
        return False
    if len(array1) != len(array2):
        return False

    array1 = sorted(array1)
    array2 = sorted(array2)

    for idx,num in enumerate(array1):
        if num*num != array2[idx]:
            return False  # early return on first mismatch
    return True
```

You still might get better results if you optimize more - but you can do that on your own time :o) - f.e. think about a check for this:

```
comp( [2]*100000000,[4]*100000000)
```

You can easily speed that up if you use a sorted list of a `set()` of your inputs instead of sorted list and that way you can eliminate about 99999999 checks which will make a dent into your runtime (unless your dataset only contains unique values to begin with). And if you got [set()'s](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) .. they are really fast in looking up if something is in them - far better and faster then sorting huge lists to begin with ...

Comment: That makes so much more sense! I didn't even know about set(). Highly appreciate your answer in such a short time.  First time using stackoverflow, really good choice :) .